# CWE 327 (Broken or Risky cryptographic Algorithm) on decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have an application that encrypts on front end and decrypts on back end using this [tutorial](https://4youngpadawans.com/end-to-end-encryption-between-react-and-spring/).

Basically backend generates public and private key then sends public key to front end and uses it to encrypt input to send back to backend for decryption.

Testing it on vera code gives me CWE 327 error in the `decryptWithAes` method,
I changed the code a bit when doing some vera code testing and pinpointed the line:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);   <---- CWE 327 is pointing here
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec , ivSpec);
```

I'm sure the iv is not  the cause since vera code will give me this error instead:

"Initialization Vector(IV) needs to be provided as part of this and this value needs to be randomized"

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your linked tutorial shows that the iv is not taken from a random value but from the user id (or parts of it): "byte []iv = user.getId().substring(0,16).getBytes();". As the user id usually won't change the iv won't change as well on subsequent encryptions. A static IV makes your complete encryption vulnerable so vera code marks it as unsecure. Generate a random IV on encryption side, pass it along with the (RSA encrypted) key and use this iv on decryption side.

Comment: However, a random key is used. Since this does not result in the repetition of key/IV pairs, the random key compensates for the static IV, s. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10081) (although not completely, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8600)). But the more common case is indeed a fixed key and a random IV, so the test logic probably assumes this and therefore classifies the static IV as faulty. However, I wonder why the random key is not simply generated with a CSPRNG, but with PBKDF2 and a _random password_ and _random salt_.

Comment: I changed the implementation and IV is now randomly generated from the front end, sent alongside with the payload to the java app for processing. However vera still returns the 327 error on the same line, is this just a false flag in vera's side?

Comment: S. [here](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D53n00007tzEjZCAU/resolving-cwe327-use-of-a-broken-or-risky-cryptographic-algorithm), last comment. Did you change your encryption/decryption as described there and does the decryption work with the separated IV?

Comment: The encryption is done in the front end and I am using asymmetric encryption (RSA for key pair) and changing it to symmetric would mean putting keys in the client side, even if the keys are in config file it isn't that secure I think. I guess  the random generated iv from the front end and sending it to the backend will suffice in this scenario.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, in particular my comment was not about replacing RSA with AES or changing the underlying concept (hybrid encryption). The linked post was meant to describe what has to be considered regarding the IV: on the encryption side: prepended to the ciphertext (at byte level); on the decryption side: separated and used for decryption. Have you done this and does the decryption work? If so, and Vera still shows an issue, it seems to me to be a false positive.

Comment: my apologies, I'm a bit out of it lately. I misunderstood your comment. Yes I've done what the comment on the link said and everything is working using random IV.

Comment: @askwer can u please post your answer? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @AmitKumarLal, I just ignored the vera code warning on the IV since it's a false positive in my case